# Apache module run under MacPorts gives SQLite error

Tags: macports, apache, sqlite

I have an Apache module, compiled from source, which works just fine with the stock Apache 2.2 on Mac OS X 10.5 through 10.7. However, under the Apache 2.2.22 installed by MacPorts, running `/opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -t` errors with `Symbol not found: _sqlite3_bind_text`.

I've verified that MacPorts' SQLite is installed, but neither the current 3.7.11 nor 3.6.12, which is the version that Snow Leopard ships with, works. I've also changed the makefile to reference /opt/local/apache2/include and /opt/local/include instead of /usr/include. Not being to familiar with such compilation, I don't know what to check for next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add this line to the makefile:

```
Darwin_LIBS += -lsqlite3
```

and the resulting module now works with MacPorts' Apache.